# JS code to show / hide all parent / child divs on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple bit of JS used to show / hide DIVs:

```
function HideShow(e, itm_id) {
var tbl = document.getElementById(itm_id);
if (tbl.style.display == ""){
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
    tbl.style.display = "none"; }
else {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
    tbl.style.display = ""; }
}
```

This is a working example of the code on Codepen: [Show Hide Divs without jQuery](https://codepen.io/paperknees/pen/bvQYpW)

This is an example of one section:

```
<div id="activities" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
    <div style="color: #000; background: #eee; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px;">
        <h1 class="heading"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this,'parent_activities')"><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> Activities <span style="color:#ccc;"></span></h1>
    </div>
        <div id="parent_activities" style="background: #fff; padding:20px;">
        <div id="activities__award-medal" style="background: #fff; padding-left:10px; background:#f1f1f1; border-top:1px solid #fff; font-size:30px;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this,'child_award-medal')"><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> award-medal <span style="color:#ccc;"></span></div>
        <div id="child_award-medal" style="background: #fff; padding:20px;">
            <ul class="gallery grid">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img title="military medal - ️" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f396.svg" style="width:64x; height:64px" role="presentation">
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="activities__event" style="background: #fff; padding-left:10px; background:#f1f1f1; border-top:1px solid #fff; font-size:30px;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this,'child_event')"><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> event <span style="color:#ccc;"></span></div>
        <div id="child_event" style="background: #fff; padding:20px;">
            <ul class="gallery grid">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img title="jack-o-lantern - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f383.svg" style="width:64x; height:64px" role="presentation">
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The top level example has an id of `parent_activities` and then there are two child values:

1. `child_award-medal`
2. `child_event`

I'd like to work out how to add two links:

1. A link to toggle the HideShow function for the parents so that all divs with an ID starting with `parent_` are shown / hidden
2. A link to toggle the HideShow function for the children so that all divs with an ID starting with `child_` are shown / hidden

I'm not sure how I'd go about that though.

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just use `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="child_"]')` to find them, then check the first ones state and apply the opposite to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following selector and apply:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="child_"]')
```

See the below snippet for an example:

```js
function toggleIdStartingWith( prefix = 'parent_' ){
  
  // Select all IDs starting with prefix and turn this NodeList into an array 
  // so we can loop through it easily later.
  var all = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="${prefix}"]`)];
  
  // Determine whether we want to turn them on or off by
  // checking the first element. You might want to also check
  // if any elements are found at all before doing this.
  var hidden = all[ 0 ].style.display === 'none';
  
  // Apply the display style to all.
  all.forEach(element => {
    
    element.style.display = hidden ? '' : 'none';
    
  });
  
  // Return the inverted hidden value, which is what we applied.
  // Useful if you want to toggle stuff, and then see what the result
  // was in the code that called the function.
  return !hidden;
  
}

// For testing purposes I am hooking two buttons up for testing this.

document.getElementById('hideshow_parents').addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  
  event.preventDefault()
  event.target.textContent = toggleIdStartingWith( 'parent_' )
    ? 'Show all Parents'
    : 'Hide all Parents'
  
})
document.getElementById('hideshow_children').addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  
  event.preventDefault()
  event.target.textContent = toggleIdStartingWith( 'child_' )
    ? 'Show all Children'
    : 'Hide all Children'
    
})
```

```html
<div id="parent_1">Parent</div>
<div id="child_1">Child</div>
<div id="parent_2">Parent</div>
<div id="child_2">Child</div>
<div id="parent_3">Parent</div>
<div id="child_3">Child</div>
<div id="parent_4">Parent</div>
<div id="child_4">Child</div>
<div id="parent_5">Parent</div>
<div id="child_5">Child</div>

<button id="hideshow_parents">Hide/Show Parents</button>
<button id="hideshow_children">Hide/Show Children</button>
```

As you asked in the comment, switching the classes depending on the toggle state is easy too. I personally think you shouldn't mix `html` and  interactivity, so I am going to use `addEventListener` in my example:

```js
function toggleIdStartingWith( prefix = 'parent_' ){
  
  var all = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="${prefix}"]`)];
  var hidden = all[ 0 ].style.display === 'none';
  
  all.forEach(element => {
    
    element.style.display = hidden ? '' : 'none';
    
  });
  
  return !hidden;
  
}

document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  
  event.preventDefault()
  
  if( toggleIdStartingWith( 'parent_' ) ){
    
    event.target.textContent = 'Show';
    event.target.classList.remove( 'fa-minus' )
    event.target.classList.add( 'fa-plus' )
    
  } else {
    
    event.target.textContent = 'Hide';
    event.target.classList.add( 'fa-minus' )
    event.target.classList.remove( 'fa-plus' )
    
  }
  
})
```

```css
.fa-minus:before { content: '-'; }
.fa-plus:before { content: '+'; }
```

```html
<div id="parent_1">Parent</div>
<div id="parent_2">Parent</div>
<div id="parent_3">Parent</div>
<div id="parent_4">Parent</div>
<div id="parent_5">Parent</div>

<h1 class="fa-minus">Hide</h1>
```

If you are insistent on getting it as an `onclick` in your html, just wrap it in a function:

```
function toggle( target, prefix ){

  if( toggleIdStartingWith( prefix ) ){

    target.textContent = 'Show';
    target.classList.remove( 'fa-minus' )
    target.classList.add( 'fa-plus' )

  } else {

    target.textContent = 'Hide';
    target.classList.add( 'fa-minus' )
    target.classList.remove( 'fa-plus' )

  }

}
```

And call it as such:

```
<h1 onclick="toggle( this, 'parent_); return false;'"></h1>
```

Also, just so you know, it might be good to `return false` if you are going to use `onclick` handlers in HTML to prevent the default events from occuring. Then you can just leave your link set to `#` instead of the ugly `javascript:;`.

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere! That worked. I edited the Codepen (https://codepen.io/paperknees/pen/bvQYpW). I wondered - would it be a lot more tricky to change the code so that e.g. when the toggle is done, when all are hidden, the minus symbols / font-awesome icon changes to a plus, and vice-versa. I realise I'm "asking for the moon on a stick" though! Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you can do it in the same way I change the text of the buttons: `if( toggleIdStartingWith( 'parent_' ) ){ event.target.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>"; } else { event.target.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>"; }` or something like that! The function returns `true` if all of them were toggled to visible, and false if they were all hidden, so just check that and apply whatever you want where ever you want it. Personally I would also use `addEventListener` instead of `href="javascript" onclick="f()"`, prevent a mix of layout and script.

Comment: @4532066 I added some more to my post to explain how you could to that easily.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and guidance! I'll follow that up soon as I have to go out now.

Answer (score 2):

***Note:*** this isn't a fully complete solution.  The intention is to assist you in the parts that are giving you pause.

---

1. Try not to embed JavaScript in your HTML body; it's unnecessary markup and makes it difficult to track down and debug errors.  I did not change your existing calls, but demonstrate how it can be done by using `addEventListener` with the newer code
2. You can target your elements using `document.querySelectorAll` and looking for the prefix you're interested in (e.g., `parent_`, `child_`).  Which prefixes to use have been added to the links in the `data-selector` attributes
3. because the toggling action is not going to another page, these should be buttons or spans
4. to hide elements, you can use the Bootstrap display classes, as I have used `d-none` which stands for display none.  The Bootstrap library provides these to make it especially easier for responsive layouts
5. many of your inline-CSS should be in classes, this is to both reduce your markup and make it more organized

```js
// So forEach can be used on 'querySelectorAll' and 'getElementsByClassName' collections
HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;


function HideShow(e, itm_id) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById(itm_id);
  if (tbl.style.display == "") {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
    tbl.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
    tbl.style.display = "";
  }
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------
// NEW Code


// New toggle links
let toggles = document.getElementsByClassName('toggler');

// Attach click event
toggles.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', fnToggleElement))

// Event handler definition
function fnToggleElement() {
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="${this.dataset.selector}"]`)
  let className = 'd-none'
  elements.forEach(el => {
    let fas = el.parentElement.closest('.item,.sub-container,.menu-container').querySelectorAll('.fa')
    if (el.classList.contains(className)) {
      el.classList.remove(className)
      fas.forEach(fa => {
        fa.classList.remove('fa-plus')
        fa.classList.add('fa-minus')
      })
    } else {
      el.classList.add(className)
      fas.forEach(fa => {
        fa.classList.remove('fa-minus')
        fa.classList.add('fa-plus')
      })
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.menu-container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.sub-container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.heading {
  color: #000;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.indent {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.icon {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.item {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.toggler {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  *width: 99.94877049180327%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
  display: block;
}

.gallery.grid li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.gallery a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"><span class="toggler btn-link" data-selector="parent_">Toggle Parents</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm"><span class="toggler btn-link" data-selector="child_">Toggle Children</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="activities" class="menu-container">
    <h1 class="heading">
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this,'parent_activities')">
        <i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
      </a> Activities
      <span style="color:#ccc;"></span>
    </h1>
    <div id="parent_activities" class="sub-container">
      <div id="activities__award-medal" class="item">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this,'child_award-medal')">
          <i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </a> award-medal
        <span style="color:#ccc;"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="child_award-medal" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="# ">
              <img title="military medal - ️" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f396.svg " class="icon" role="presentation">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="activities__event " class="item">
        <a href="javascript:; " onclick="HideShow(this, 'child_event') ">
          <i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </a> event
        <span style="color:#ccc; "></span>
      </div>
      <div id="child_event " class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid ">
          <li>
            <a href="# ">
              <img title="jack-o-lantern - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f383.svg" class="icon" role="presentation">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="animals-nature" class="menu-container">
    <h1 class="heading"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this, 'parent_animals-nature')"><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> Animals & Nature <span style="color:#ccc;"></span></h1>
    <div id="parent_animals-nature" class="sub-container">

      <div id="animals-nature__animal-amphibian " class="item ">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this, 'child_animal-amphibian')">
          <i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </a> animal-amphibian
        <span style="color:#ccc;"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="child_animal-amphibian" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="# ">
              <img title="frog face -  " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f438.svg " style="width:64x; height:64px " role="presentation ">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="animals-nature__animal-bird " class="item">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="HideShow(this, 'child_animal-bird')">
          <i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </a> animal-bird
        <span style="color:#ccc;"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="child_animal-bird" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="# ">
              <img title="turkey -  " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f983.svg " style="width:64x; height:64px " role="presentation ">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for that! I take your point about splitting out the inline-css, it makes the HTML a lot more readable. Thanks again!

Comment: I also mean, thanks for all of the work you did to help me out, not just the bit about the inline-css.

Comment: I didn't put much effort to what it was doing, which is why one of them is even named `indent`, my guess if given more scrutiny, you should end up with some sort of hierarchical naming system.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to select "IDs starting with...". This can be done like `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="start_"]')` and then you iterate through the elements applying the style to hide or show.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1c38dezk/

Comment: Stack overflow has these nice snippets you can use instead of linking to a fiddle. Also, thats paraphrasing what I said.

Comment: I'd rather use the fiddle so whoever opens it can play around. Also, you commented while I was typing my answer, so no paraphrasing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use querySelectorAll() to select "IDs starting with...".
Have a nice day